# Linear dependency for vectors $1,\sin(x),\cos(x) \in \text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Show that the following vectors are linearly dependent/independent:
> $$I. 1, \sin(x),\cos(x) \in \text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$
> $$II. 1, \sin^2(x),\cos^2(x) \in \text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$

I know that the vectors in I. are linearly independent and  the vectors in II. are linearly dependent, but how should I prove it?

Comment: Have you tried to write down what it means for vectors to be linearly dependent, linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, but I struggle to know, what it means for $\text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$

Comment: It means exactly the same thing as for vectors. Just have in mind what it means for a map to be vanishing for all $x \in mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) to  prove linear independence. In the case $I$, you should get $1$ and in the case $II$ you should get 0.